# Is it possible to Invalidate the .manifest Cache with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, manifest

The Webapplication we're currently building is using a .manifest file to make it available offline. In the top right of the application we display the username. All other context is requested through ajax.

Now the problem is that when the user log's out and a different one logs in the username field stays the same because the browser cached that page already.

So my question is: Is it possible to invalidate the manifest file upon logout with javascript?

I am aware that we could fill the username field through ajax too.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I don't know a programmatically way to do it, a great common pattern for web apps is to use app cache for the resources that are common to all users and use other storage mechanisms (localStorage, indexedDB, etc) for specific user data.